# SQL Server 2008 Filestream Impersonation Access Denied error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, filestream, impersonation

I've been trying to upload a file to the database using SQL SERVER 2008 Filestream and Impersonation technique to save the file in the file system, but i keep getting Access Denied error; even though i've set the permissions for the impersonating user to the Filestream folder(C:\SQLFILESTREAM\Dev_DB). when i debugged the code, i found the server return a unc path(\Server_Name\MSSQLSERVER\v1\Dev_LMDB\dbo\FileData\File_Data\13C39AB1-8B91-4F5A-81A1-940B58504C17), which was not accessible through windows explorer.
I've my web application hosted on local maching(Windows 7). SQL Server is located on a remote server(Windows Server 2008 R2). Sql authentication was used to call the stored procedure.

Following is the code i've used to do the above operations.

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("AddFile");
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@File_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512).Value = filename;
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@File_Type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = Path.GetExtension(filename);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = username;
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Output_File_Path", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

DAManager PDAM = new DAManager(DAManager.getConnectionString());
using (SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)PDAM.CreateConnection())
{
     connection.Open();
     SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

     WindowsImpersonationContext wImpersonationCtx;
     NetworkSecurity ns = null;
     try
     {
          PDAM.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlCmd, transaction);
          string filepath = sqlCmd.Parameters["@Output_File_Path"].Value.ToString();
          sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()");
          sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

          byte[] Context = (byte[])PDAM.ExecuteScalar(sqlCmd, transaction);
          byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
          int bytedRead;

          ns = new NetworkSecurity();
          wImpersonationCtx = ns.ImpersonateUser(IMP_Domain, IMP_Username, IMP_Password, LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT);

          SqlFileStream sfs = new SqlFileStream(filepath, Context, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
          while ((bytedRead = inFS.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
          {
               sfs.Write(buffer, 0, bytedRead);
          }
          sfs.Close();

          transaction.Commit();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          transaction.Rollback();
     }
     finally
     {
          sqlCmd.Dispose();
          connection.Close();
          connection.Dispose();
          ns.undoImpersonation();
          wImpersonationCtx = null;
          ns = null;
     }
}
```

Can someone help me with this issue.
[Reference](http://www.aghausman.net/dotnet/saving-and-retrieving-file-using-filestream-sql-server-2008.html)

```
Exception:
Type : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Message : Access is denied Source : System.Data Help link : 
NativeErrorCode : 5
ErrorCode : -2147467259
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : Void OpenSqlFileStream(System.String, Byte[], System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileOptions, Int64)
Stack Trace :    at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream.OpenSqlFileStream(String path, Byte[] transactionContext, FileAccess access, FileOptions options, Int64 allocationSize)
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream..ctor(String path, Byte[] transactionContext, FileAccess access, FileOptions options, Int64 allocationSize)
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream..ctor(String path, Byte[] transactionContext, FileAccess access)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql authentication is not supported when accessing Filestream data

[FILESTREAM Storage in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109.aspx)

Comment: Impersonating the user with integrated security solved the problem.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlnetfx/thread/157971a4-335f-4138-bdf8-89d0a20f0031

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK rather than LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE. I encountered this error many years ago using API calls for UNC impersonation, so maybe it still holds.

Comment: Chris, changing it to LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK didn't work for me. I've added the exception details and the unc path. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: So the esssential nature of this is that your process is presenting a security token, and the system is comparing the token against an ACL and not finding it.

Comment: What might be helpful here would be to run Process Monitor on the TARGET server, and look for the details of the Access Denied entry; I suspect that the process may not have the identity we are expecting. Process Monitor can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The solution was to check all checkboxes on the "FileStream" tab of the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Here are the instructions on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923(v=sql.100).aspx

Note points 7 and 8:

> 1. If you want to read and write FILESTREAM data from Windows, click Enable FILESTREAM for file I/O streaming access. Enter the name of the
>      Windows share in the Windows Share Name box.
> 2. If remote clients must access the FILESTREAM data that is stored on this share, select Allow remote clients to have streaming access to
>      FILESTREAM data.

We had remote clients accessing the file stream thus we needed all check boxes enabled, and originally we only checked the first three, which caused the error.